# Line-Polygon intersection: trying to implement Modified Simpson's Rule for Left Ventricle volume estimation

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, image-segmentation

Basically, modified Simpson's rule is the standard empirical measurement for left ventricle volume estimation (typically using echocardiography). I am trying to implement this method from scratch using OpenCV and Python. I was able to get the length from apex to base but I need to get the diameter of disks passing through the vertical line.

Sample left ventricle contour. [A] is contour of LV, [B] is the vertical line from apex to base, and [C] are the diameters of disks. (Sorry for the poor drawing, I don't think I am allowed to share prediction results of my Segmentation Model).

[image: 1]

**My question is:** how can I determine the disk diameters which pass through the vertical line and all of which must have the same slope? That is C1, C2,...,C20 must have the same slopes and pass through the vertical line. Or is it not necessary for them to have the same slope?

My current method for determining these diameters involves getting the contour points, then split the list into two based on vertical line endpoints. Then draw a line from points in one list with the points in the other list.

```py
def get_disks(img,mask):
  #img: mask image in RGB
  #mask: output of segmentation model (in grayscale)

  cnts = cv.findContours(mask,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  c1 = cv.line(img,((int(cnts[5,0]),int(cnts[5,1]))),((int(cnts[-5,0]),int(cnts[-5,1])))

  ...

  return img
```

Thanks!

Comment: and the diameters/disks can be spaced arbitrarily closely? looks like an integral. so yes they do need the same slope. -- anyway, you'll need some "simple" linear algebra to calculate a normal vector to your B line. you need the points for apex and base. then you would consider a bunch of points along B, and then you'd need to find how far the normal line through each point has to extend to meet the contour. line-polygon intersection could be a little tricky but there exist algorithms for that.

Comment: Yes, all the lines/diameters need to be at the same angle, a good choice would be a gradient that is perpendicular to the gradient of B. If you have a thresholded binary image then you can sent test lines across the image & note where it crosses the vetricle boundaries, then the center of your disk is half the distence between the boundaries.

Comment: if you don't like geometry algorithms, you could "cheat", and instead rotate the *mask image* so B is upright (simple rotation and `warpAffine`). then you could sample the mask row-wise. finding the first and last white pixel in a row of pixels is fairly simple.